# Constrained protocol still complaining as being generic

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

So first of all, I understand that protocols having `associatedtype` in them would become generic  that it makes no sense to use them as properties. The question however is why would protocols being already constrained still fall under the "being generic" nature?

For example:

```swift
protocol ItemCollection {
    associatedtype ItemType
    var items: [ItemType]
}

protocol StringItemCollectable: ItemCollection where ItemType == String {
    // other implementation
}

class Foo {
    // item model
    var itemCollectionModel: StringItemCollectable? // Compiler here is still complaining about using generic protocols

}
```

If I create a concrete type that conforms to `StringItemCollectable`, the compiler would know that `items` are an array of `String`.

```swift
struct TestCollectionModel: StringItemCollectable {
    var items: [String] // this would be required and already known from the compiler
}
```

Why would the compiler think the constrained protocol in `class Foo` is still generic?

Comment: A protocol it is not a type.

Comment: You need a class or struct that adheres to the protocol, and then you can use that class/struct the way you are now.  For ex. `struct StringItemCollection:  StringItemCollectable { var items: [String] = [] }`

Comment: I believe this is an exact duplicate. If there are further issues that you think aren't covered there, ping me and we can reopen this. The short answer is that this is not a current feature of Swift; once a protocol has an associated type, it can never be made back into a simple protocol. It's not a type problem; Swift just doesn't do this.